# covariance between two columns in pandas groupby pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to calculate the covariance between two columns by group. I am doing doing the following:

```
A = pd.DataFrame({'group':['A','A','A','A','B','B','B'],
                  'value1':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7],
                  'value2':[8,5,4,3,7,8,8]})

B = A.groupby('group')

B['value1'].cov(B['value2'])
```

Ideally, I would like to get the covariance between X and Y and not the whole variance-covariance matrix, since I only have two columns.

Thank you,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are almost there, only that you do not clear understand the groupby object, see [Pandas-GroupBy](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html) for more details.

For your problem, if I understand correctly, you would like to calculate cov between two columns in same group.

The simplest one is to use `groupeby.cov` function, which gives pairwise cov between groups.

```
A.groupby('group').cov()

                value1    value2
group                           
A     value1  1.666667 -2.666667
      value2 -2.666667  4.666667
B     value1  1.000000  0.500000
      value2  0.500000  0.333333
```

If you only need cov(grouped_v1, grouped_v2)

```
grouped = A.groupby('group')
grouped.apply(lambda x: x['value1'].cov(x['value2']))

group
A   -2.666667
B    0.500000
```

In which, `grouped` is a `groupby` object. For `grouped.apply` function, it need a callback function as argument and each group will be the argument for the callback function. Here, the callback function is a `lambda` function, and the argument `x` is a group (a DataFrame).

Hope this will be helpful for your understanding of groupby.

Answer (score 2):

The following code gives you the grouped variance-covariance matrix. You can subset it as you wish to just get the covariances.

```
import pandas as pd
A = pd.DataFrame({'group':['A','A','A','A','B','B','B'],
                  'value1':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7],
                  'value2':[8,5,4,3,7,8,8]})
print A.groupby('group').cov()
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternative solution that estimates `cov(value1, value2)` within each group, but doesn't use `.apply()`:

```py
import pandas as pd

A = pd.DataFrame({'group':['A','A','A','A','B','B','B'],
                  'value1':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7],
                  'value2':[8,5,4,3,7,8,8]})

B = A.groupby('group')

cov_a_b = B[['value1', 'value2']].cov(ddof=0)['value1'].unstack()['value2']
```

As an additional note somewhat related to the question, you should be careful when using the NumPy/Pandas implementations of variance and covariance, as they use a degrees of freedom correction of 1 by default (confusingly, NumPy defaults to `ddof=0` for their implementation of variance). This is why I included `ddof=0`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for `cov()` of specific two columns, you can use `df.Age.cov(df.Salary)`
Assuming that Age and salary are two of many columns of the dataFrame. This is useful for only two columns.